# Finding similarity score between two columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
ID,Region,Supplier,year,output
1,Test,Test1,2021,1
2,dummy,tUMMY,2022,1
3,dasho,MASHO,2022,1
4,dahp,ZYZE,2021,0
5,delphi,POQE,2021,1
6,kilby,Daasan,2021,1
7,sarby,abbas,2021,1

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

My objective is

a) To compare two column values and assign a similarity score.

So, I tried the below

```
import difflib
[(len(difflib.get_close_matches(x, df['Region'], cutoff=0.6))>1)*1
 for x in df['Supplier']]
```

However, this gives all output to be '0'. Meaning less than cut-off value of 0.6

However, I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated answer with similarity flag and score (using `difflib.SequenceMatcher`)

```py
cutoff = 0.6

df['similarity_score'] = (
    df[['Region','Supplier']]
    .apply(lambda x: difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, x[0].lower(), x[1].lower()).ratio(), axis=1)
)

df['similarity_flag'] = (df['similarity_score'] >= cutoff).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   ID  Region Supplier  year  output  similarity_score  similarity_flag
0   1    Test    Test1  2021       1          0.888889                1
1   2   dummy    tUMMY  2022       1          0.800000                1
2   3   dasho    MASHO  2022       1          0.800000                1
3   4    dahp     ZYZE  2021       0          0.000000                0
4   5  delphi     POQE  2021       1          0.200000                0
5   6   kilby   Daasan  2021       1          0.000000                0
6   7   sarby    abbas  2021       1          0.200000                0
```

---

Try using `apply` with `lambda` and `axis=1`:

```py
df['similarity_flag'] = (
    df[['Region','Supplier']]
    .apply(lambda x: len(difflib.get_close_matches(x[0].lower(), [x[1].lower()])), axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
   ID  Region Supplier  year  output  similarity_flag
0   1    Test    Test1  2021       1                1
1   2   dummy    tUMMY  2022       1                1
2   3   dasho    MASHO  2022       1                1
3   4    dahp     ZYZE  2021       0                0
4   5  delphi     POQE  2021       1                0
5   6   kilby   Daasan  2021       1                0
6   7   sarby    abbas  2021       1                0
```

Comment: how come you don't use cutoff check? but still get similarity_flag as 1 and 0? Is it possible to show the raw cut off value as a column as well?

Comment: The cutoff is 0.6 by default. You can simply set a variable to the cutoff, use it in the function, and create a new column for it with `df[cutoff_val] = cutoff`. As far as I know, this function doesn't return the similarity score.

Comment: @TheGreat, I've updated the answer with the similarity score, but the usage of another function was necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Converting each column to lower case and making the comparison `>=` rather than `>` (since there is at most one match in this examples) fetches the desired output:

```py
from difflib import SequenceMatcher, get_close_matches
df['best_match'] = [x for x in df['Supplier'].str.lower() for x in get_close_matches(x, df['Region'].str.lower()) or ['']]
df['similarity_score'] = df.apply(lambda x: SequenceMatcher(None, x['Supplier'].lower(), x['best_match']).ratio(), axis=1)
df = df.assign(similarity_flag = df['similarity_score'].gt(0.6).astype(int)).drop(columns=['best_match'])
```

Output:

```py
  ID  Region Supplier  year  output  similarity_score  similarity_flag
0   1    Test    Test1  2021       1          0.888889                1
1   2   dummy    tUMMY  2022       1          0.800000                1
2   3   dasho    MASHO  2022       1          0.800000                1
3   4    dahp     ZYZE  2021       0          0.000000                0
4   5  delphi     POQE  2021       1          0.000000                0
5   6   kilby   Daasan  2021       1          0.000000                0
6   7   sarby    abbas  2021       1          0.000000                0
```

Comment: Is it possible to show the raw cut off value as a column as well?

Comment: @TheGreat what do you mean by raw cut off value?

Comment: Meaning, some values may have 0.8 as score, some values may have 0.9 as score etc. Sorry, I meant similarity score (and not cut off)

Comment: Edited the answer. Please see if it works.